# debezium-ui cannot connect to the debezium-connect-cluster-connect-api service

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium, debezium-server

**Hello**
I recently deployed **debezium-ui** on Kubernetes cluster, but I can't access "debezium-connect-cluster-connect-api" service due to network policy.
How can I modify or delete the network policy service in kafkaconnect?

List of services:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npvIR.png)

List of Network Policies:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yf0A.png)

"debezium-connect-cluster-connect" Network Policy content:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGgWp.png)